# How to apply filter condition on two embedded field in django mongoengine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using django with mongoengine. I tried all query top solve this. I also tried raw query but not success.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("556fe5c338a01311c4c4d1c1"),
  "uuid" : "5c8ae1dfcb1d060d5a951d96d4798a84cdf090e9",
  "snapshot_values" : [{
      "key" : "gender",
      "value" : "Female",
    }, {
      "key" : "marital_status",
      "value" : "married",
    }],
},

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("556fe5c338a01311c4c4d1c1"),
  "uuid" : "5c8ae1dfcb1d060d5a951d96d4798a84cdf090e9",
  "snapshot_values" : [{
      "key" : "gender",
      "value" : "Female",
    }, {
      "key" : "marital_status",
      "value" : "unmarried",
    }],
},

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("556fe5c338a01311c4c4d1c1"),
  "uuid" : "5c8ae1dfcb1d060d5a951d96d4798a84cdf090e9",
  "snapshot_values" : [{
      "key" : "gender",
      "value" : "Female",
    }, {
      "key" : "marital_status",
      "value" : "married",
    }],
},
```

Here i want to apply select those data who has key=marital_status and value=married.

```
condition1:
{key=marital_status, value=married},   will return two data,

condition:2
{key=marital_status,value=unmarried}, and {key=gender,value=female}, will return singe raw data from above data.
```

Anyone know how to make query which satisfy above conditions.

Pleas give me suggestion, even little help, suggestion will be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For the first condition, try the following query which uses the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of an embedded document:

```
db.user.find({
    "snapshot_values.key": "marital_status", 
    "snapshot_values.value": "married"
})
```

For the second condition, use the following query that takes advantage of the **[`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator:

```
db.user.find({
    "snapshot_values.key": { "$in": ["marital_status", "gender"] }, 
    "snapshot_values.value": { "$in": ["unmarried", "female"] }
})
```

---

-- **UPDATE** --

The django mongoengine version should be something like the following example where you can use the **[Q class](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries)**:

For the first condition

```
Person_Snapshot.objects(Q(snapshot_values__key="marital_status") & Q(snapshot_values__value="marries")
```

Second condition (uses the **[query operator](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators)** in)

```
key_list = ["marital_status", "gender"]
value_list = ["unmarried", "female"]
Person_Snapshot.objects(Q(snapshot_values__key__in=key_list) & Q(snapshot_values__value__in=value_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Actually i am using django with mongoengine, So i think, i can't use this pure mongo query. 

Can u please give mongoengine query? 

it will be like this,
Person_Snapshot.objects(__raw__={ '$and': [{'snapshot_values.key': 'marital_status','snapshot_values.value': marital_status_select }]})

Comment: @jatin Updated my answer, though untested I'm sure you can try the update out or refer to the [**docs**](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#filtering-queries) for more detail.

Comment: +1 vote for your effort and answer, but thisdoesn't solve my problem, the query must return only one raw for second condition